Failed to Close the Sales order through button
I am trying to send the params to suitlet it capturing the params but failed to close the order i need assistance i am new bee in suitscripts
I Added a user Event for adding a button on sales order with the status pending approval or pending fulfillments. but when i click the button it unable to close the order but it showing me the sales order id on the suitelet page before click the button, After click the button
Client Script :
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 */
define(['N/url', 'N/ui/dialog', 'N/log', 'N/currentRecord'], (url, dialog, log, currentRecord) => {
    function pageInit(scriptContext) {

    }

    function showPopup() {
        try {
            const currentRec = currentRecord.get();
            const salesOrderId = currentRec.id;
            const paramsId = {
                orderId : salesOrderId
            }

            const suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
                scriptId: 'customscript_bits_ss_close_sales_order',
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_bits_ss_close_sales_order',
                params: paramsId
            });
            dialog.create({
                title: 'Cancel/Close Order',
                message: `<iframe src="${suiteletUrl}" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; border: none;"></iframe>`,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        label: 'Cancel',
                        value: 'close',
                        action: () => dialog.close()
                    }
                ]
            });

        } catch (error) {
            log.error('Error in showPopup', error.message);
            alert('An error occurred while opening the popup. Check the logs for details.');
        }
    }

    return {
        pageInit,
        showPopup
    };
});

Suitlet Script:
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/log'], (record, serverWidget, log) => {
    const onRequest = (scriptContext) => {
        const request = scriptContext.request;
        const response = scriptContext.response;

        const salesOrderId = request.parameters['orderId'] ;
        log.debug('Sales Order ID Received', salesOrderId);

        if (!salesOrderId) {
            response.write('<p>Error: Sales Order ID is missing.</p>');
            return;
        }

        if (request.method === 'GET') {
            try {
                const salesOrder = record.load({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    id: salesOrderId
                });
                log.debug('Sales Order Loaded Successfully', salesOrder);

                const form = serverWidget.createForm({
                    title: `Close Sales Order - ID: ${salesOrderId}`,
                    hideNavBar: true
                });

                form.addField({
                    id: 'custpage_message',
                    type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
                    label: 'Message'
                }).defaultValue = `<p>Are you sure you want to cancel Sales Order ID: ${salesOrderId}?</p>`;

                form.addSubmitButton({ label: 'Confirm Cancellation' });

                form.addButton({
                    id: 'custpage_cancel',
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    functionName: 'window.close();'
                });

                response.writePage(form);
            } catch (error) {
                log.error('Error Loading Sales Order', error);
                response.write('<p>Error: Unable to load the Sales Order. Check the ID and try again.</p>');
            }
        } else if (request.method === 'POST') {
            try {
                const salesOrder = record.load({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    id: salesOrderId
                });

                const lineCount = salesOrder.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' });
                for (let i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
                    salesOrder.setSublistValue({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'isclosed',
                        line: i,
                        value: true
                    });
                }

                salesOrder.save();
                response.write('<script>alert("Sales Order canceled successfully."); window.close();</script>');
            } catch (error) {
                log.error('Error Cancelling Sales Order', error);
                response.write('<script>alert("Failed to cancel the Sales Order."); window.close();</script>');
            }
        }
    };

    return { onRequest };
});

Please help me to close the sales order through button on sales order
